# Creating a GatewayAuthorizer through CloudFormation failing - concurrent modification

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I'm writing a CF template that contains an API Gateway with some endpoints, a Cognito User Pool with associated Domain and Client, an IDP and an Authorizer. The Gateway is created successfully, as is the Pool and the IDP.

However, the Authorizer is not created successfully. It essentially sits in CREATE_IN_PROGRESS for a very long time and then fails with a ConflictException / Concurrent modification exception:

```
{
    ... events ...
    "eventTime": "2022-06-24T18:49:48Z",
    "eventSource": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "CreateAuthorizer",
    "awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "cloudformation.amazonaws.com",
    "userAgent": "cloudformation.amazonaws.com",
    "errorCode": "ConflictException",
    "requestParameters": {
        "identitySource": [
            "$request.header.Authorization"
        ],
        "name": "JwtCognitoAuthorizer",
        "jwtConfiguration": {
            "audience": [
                "3t5s..."
            ],
            "issuer": "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1:223249055027.amazonaws.com/eu-west-1_orEMePYWZ"
        },
        "authorizerType": "JWT",
        "apiId": "us0ekpcxhc"
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "message": "Unable to complete operation due to concurrent modification. Please try again later."
    },
...
}
```

I'm using the below CF snippet for  the Authorizer:

```
  APIGatewayAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Authorizer
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref apiGateway
      AuthorizerType: JWT
      IdentitySource:
        - "$request.header.Authorization"
      JwtConfiguration:
        Audience:
          - !Ref UserPoolClient
        Issuer: !Sub 'https://cognito-idp.${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}.amazonaws.com/${UserPool}'
      Name: JwtCognitoAuthorizer
```

Concurrent modification makes it sound like some sort of dependency issue (maybe things are being created in the wrong order?) but I thought CloudFormation dealt with that itself.

I couldn't see any other question which dealt with this specifically - any suggestions or links appreciated.

Thanks